# PostgreSQL regex with OR condition in SUBSTRING function

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to recognize TIMESTAMP in PostgreSQL by using regexp:

`SELECT substring('13:14:00', '([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d')`

This query returns `13`, but I need to receive result `13:14:00`.

Analogical query `SELECT substring('134', '1(2|3)4')` returns `3` instead of `134`.

So, what is the problem? My psql version is 9.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parenthesis:

```
  SELECT substring('13:14:00', '(([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)');
```